# Update SSRS Datasource Reference in Powershell before Upload

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, encoding, ssrs-2012

I hope somebody can help me with this issue, i am trying to upload an SSRS report using powershell, however it totally loses the datasource reference after its uploaded.

I found some script online which changes the reference, but this would not work for what i need because its using the datasource name to become the reference, but in my scenario the datasource name could be something like Datasource1 but the reference could be /Data Sources/Translations

What i need to do is alter the reference in the bytearray before its uploaded.

This is the script im using so far, which is working for the upload.

```
#ReportName
$reportName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($rdlFile);
write-host $reportName -ForegroundColor Green
#Upload File
try
{
#Get Report content in bytes
Write-Host "Getting file content of : $rdlFile"
$byteArray = gc $rdlFile.FullName -encoding Byte

$msg = "Total length: {0}" -f $byteArray.Length
Write-Host $msg

Write-Host "Uploading to: $reportFolder_Final"

$type = $ssrsProxy.GetType().Namespace
$datatype = ($type + '.Property')

$DescProp = New-Object($datatype)
$DescProp.Name = 'Description'
$DescProp.Value = ''
$HiddenProp = New-Object($datatype)
$HiddenProp.Name = 'Hidden'
$HiddenProp.Value = 'false'
$Properties = @($DescProp, $HiddenProp)

#Call Proxy to upload report

$warnings = $null

$Results = $ssrsProxy.CreateCatalogItem("Report",$reportName,$reportFolder_Final, $IsOverwriteReport,$byteArray,$Properties,[ref]$warnings)
```

If i try reading the XML in as a string and then converting it back into a bytearray before uploading it to the ssrs server the upload fails as it complains about the formatting. I had plans of reading it in as a string, altering the datasource reference, encoding it and then uploading but thats the part i need your help with doing.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

i have managed to suss this out, for anyone having similar issues i used the following code to read the data in from the XML file as a system.byte, converted it into a UTF8 string, made my changes to the references and then converted it back to a UTF8 Bytestream before uploading to the report server WDSL

```
$byteArray = gc $rdlFile.FullName -encoding Byte
$byteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($byteArray)
$byteArray = $byteArray -replace "<DataSourceReference>", "<DataSourceReference>/Data Sources/"
$byteArray = $byteArray -replace "<SharedDataSetReference>", "<SharedDataSetReference>/Datasets/"
$byteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($byteArray)
```